# Some incoherence in the headers when using the memoir class

Tags: header-footer, margins, memoir, page-numbering, article

so I'm using the memoir documentclass and I'm facing some problems:

I'm getting wrong margins and line spacing (not the desired output) although I set them in the preamble as following:

```
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm,textwidth=209.9mm,textheight=296.7mm]{geometry}

% line spacing of 1.5
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.241}
```

I get the header visible in the abstract section and when trying to remove it, the headers in all other pages disappear. I tried `\thispagestyle{empty}` but it keeps removing it from all pages

Another thing I want is to start page numbering from the table of contents. I tried this but nothing had changed:

```
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Can you please help me solve this problems. This is my first time using LaTeX and I couldn't find time to practice well.

Here is a bit of code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir} % for a long document

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding to utf8
\usepackage[left=35mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm,textwidth=209.9mm,textheight=296.7mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options
\usepackage{subfig} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % This should be set AFTER setting up the page geometry
\usepackage{setspace}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\setlength{\parskip}{2em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.241}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{*}{\lxvchars}{1.618} % we want to the text block to have golden proportionals
\setulmargins{25mm}{*}{*} % 50pt upper margins
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.618} % golden ratio again for left/right margins
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{1.618}
\checkandfixthelayout 
\pretitle{\begin{center}\sffamily\huge\MakeUppercase}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
%%% ToC (table of contents) APPEARANCE
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % include subsections
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{}     % no bold!

%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\pagestyle{companion} % try also: empty , plain , headings , ruled , Ruled , companion

%%% CHAPTERS
\chapterstyle{companion} % try also: default , section , hangnum , companion , article, demo

\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\raggedright} % set sans serif chapter title font
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\sffamily\raggedright} % set sans serif chapter number font

%%% SECTIONS
%\hangsecnum % hang the section numbers into the margin to match \chapterstyle{hangnum}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % number subsections
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\raggedright} % set sans serif section font
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\raggedright} % set sans serif subsection font
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\sffamily\raggedright\textbf} % set sans serif subsubsection font
%% END Memoir customization

\title{title}
\author{author}
%\date{} % Delete this line to display the current date

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\thispagestyle{empty}

\justifying
%\pagestyle{empty}
\section*{abstract}
\lipsum{3}
\section*{résumé}
\lipsum{3}
\newpage

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents* % the asterisk means that the contents itself isn't put into the ToC
\chapter{C1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.

\section{s1}
\subsection{ss1}
\subsubsection{sss1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.
\subsubsection{sss2} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.
\subsubsection{sss3} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.

\subsection{ss2}
\subsubsection{sss1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.
\subsubsection{sss2} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.
\section{s2}

\chapter{c2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test. Note that memoir has its own build in system for setting both the margins and line spacings, though `geometry` should work with it as well. But as long as you don't provide a full example we have no idea what exactly you are referring to

Comment: @daleif You can check the post again. I added a little bit of code.

Comment: You should no be using `fancyhdr` and pages style `fancy` with `memoir` it has it own much more integrated system. Also do use `geometry` _and_ memoirs setup. Don't use `tabu` it is unmaintanied and have several issues.

Comment: `hyperref` should be the last package loaded (with a few exceptions)

Comment: For the `abstract` you'll need to use `the `\pagestyle{empty}` and reissue `\pagestyle{companion}` when it should go back to normal

Comment: Since `\maketitle` issues `\thispagestyle{title}` you might want to alias it to `empty` via `\aliaspagestyle{title}{empty}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adjusted version of the MWE. I've removed irrelevant packages

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir} % for a long document
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} # then \justifying is not needed
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding to utf8
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\setlength{\parskip}{2em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.241}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{*}{\lxvchars}{1.618} % we want to the text block to have golden proportionals
\setulmargins{25mm}{*}{*} % 50pt upper margins
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.618} % golden ratio again for left/right margins
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{1.618}
\checkandfixthelayout 
\pretitle{\begin{center}\sffamily\huge\MakeUppercase}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
%%% ToC (table of contents) APPEARANCE
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % include subsections
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{}     % no bold!

%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\pagestyle{companion} % try also: empty , plain , headings , ruled , Ruled , companion

%%% CHAPTERS
\chapterstyle{companion} % try also: default , section , hangnum , companion , article, demo
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\raggedright} % set sans serif chapter title font
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\raggedright} % set sans serif chapter number font


%%% SECTIONS
%\hangsecnum % hang the section numbers into the margin to match \chapterstyle{hangnum}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % number subsections
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\raggedright} % set sans serif section font
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\raggedright} % set sans serif subsection font
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\sffamily\raggedright\bfseries} % set sans serif subsubsection font
%% END Memoir customization

% no page number on page with \maketitle
\aliaspagestyle{title}{empty}


\title{title}
\author{author}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

% cheating hyperref, then it doesn't warn about preexisting targets
% due to the "blank" pages

\pagenumbering{Alph}

\maketitle


\pagestyle{empty}
\section*{abstract}
\lipsum{3}
\section*{résumé}
\lipsum{3}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{companion}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\tableofcontents* % the asterisk means that the contents itself isn't put into the ToC

\chapter{C1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.

\section{s1}
\subsection{ss1}
\subsubsection{sss1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.
\subsubsection{sss2} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.
\subsubsection{sss3} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.

\subsection{ss2}
\subsubsection{sss1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.
\subsubsection{sss2} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.
\section{s2}

\chapter{c2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works now! Last question that I forgot to mention in the post: **What is the best package to use to set the font family to Times New Roman?**

Comment: Don't use `Time New Roman`. See for example, https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/texgyretermes/ (Nimbus is a Times clone). Otherwise you'll probably need to move to `lualatex` and through it use `Time New Roman` if it is on you PC.

Comment: BTW: remember to accept the question if it solved your problem.

Comment: Answer accepted!